# How to set default year from current timestamp in phpMyAdmin page without SQL query command manually

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to store scholarship database for subscribe the students that interest in each scholarship. But can I set the year from `current_timestamp()` in phpMyAdmin page without typing the SQL command manually.

The table definiton contains.

```
ScholarshipID int primary auto_increment
Title varchar(250)
Paragraph varchar(5000)
Year year(4) default current_timestamp()
CreatedAt datetime default current_timestamp()
UpdatedAt datetime default current_timestamp() on update current_timestamp()
```

I'm found out that Year row values is inserted as string.
[image: I'm found out that Year row values is inserted as string.]

And the result if I save the inserted data.
[image: And the result if I save the inserted data.]

The SQL query that I expected to be.

```
INSERT INTO `scholarship_program` (`ScholarshipID`, `Title`, `Paragraph`, `Year`, `CreatedAt`, `UpdatedAt`) VALUES (NULL, 'หัวข้อข่าวทุนการศึกษา', 'เนื้อหาข่าวทุนการศึกษา\r\n- ใจความ\r\n- เนื้อหาละเอียด\r\n- สรุปเนื้อหา\r\nทิ้งท้าย', YEAR(current_timestamp()), current_timestamp(), current_timestamp());
```

The SQL query result from phpMyAdmin.

```
INSERT INTO `scholarship_program` (`ScholarshipID`, `Title`, `Paragraph`, `Year`, `CreatedAt`, `UpdatedAt`) VALUES (NULL, 'หัวข้อข่าวทุนการศึกษา', 'เนื้อหาข่าวทุนการศึกษา\r\n- ใจความ\r\n- เนื้อหาละเอียด\r\n- สรุปเนื้อหา\r\nทิ้งท้าย', 'current_timestamp()', current_timestamp(), current_timestamp());
```

I'm tried to use function `YEAR` but it has an error. Because it treated `current_timestamp()` as string.

SQL Query.

```
INSERT INTO `scholarship_program` (`ScholarshipID`, `Title`, `Paragraph`, `Year`, `CreatedAt`, `UpdatedAt`) VALUES (NULL, 'Scholarship News Header.', 'Scholarship News Paragraph.', YEAR('current_timestamp()'), current_timestamp(), current_timestamp())
```

SQL Said.
`#1048 - Column 'Year' cannot be null`

Comment: Which database management system are you using? MariaDB or MySQL?

Comment: Congrats to those who can read those images..For those of us who can't please consider adding table definition , sample data, expected output and code attempt as text.

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa 
How could I check which my database management system is MariaDB or MySQL. I checked in directory and see it's name so I guess it is MySQL.

Comment: @PaweenwatManeechai `select version();`

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa 10.4.22-MariaDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could instead use a [TRIGGER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) to supply a default value for the "*Year*" column.

1. Alter the "Year" column data type.

```sql
ALTER TABLE scholarship_program MODIFY Year YEAR NULL;
```

2. Set up a trigger ("BEFORE INSERT").

```sql
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `scholarship_program_insert_default_year`;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER scholarship_program_insert_default_year
BEFORE INSERT ON scholarship_program FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    SET NEW.Year = TRIM(NEW.Year);
    
    IF (NEW.Year IS NULL) OR (NEW.Year = '') THEN
        SET NEW.Year=YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

3. To insert a new record, you can now pass a `NULL` value for the "Year" column.

```sql
INSERT INTO `scholarship_program` (`ScholarshipID`, `Title`, `Paragraph`, `Year`, `CreatedAt`, `UpdatedAt`) VALUES (NULL, 'Bsc in computer science', 'Learning about PCs...', NULL, current_timestamp(), current_timestamp());
```

Your "PHPMyAdmin" application will also work fine without errors.

Comment: Thank a lot. I don't ever know before that SQL can use logic programming like this.